# Using a Regular Expression to Find XML character references for control characters

Tags: xml, regex, control-characters

I need some help figuring out the regex for XML character references to control characters, in decimal or hex.

These sequences look like the following:

> &#0;
>   &#x03;
>   &#31;
>   &#x1f;
>   &#x1F;

In other words, they are an ampersand, followed by a pound, followed by an optional 'x' to denote hexadecimal mode, followed by 1 to 4 decimal (or hexadecimal) digits, followed by a semicolon.

I'm specifically trying to identify those sequences where they contain (inclusive) numbers from decimal 0 to 31, or hexadecimal 0 to 1F.

Can anyone figure out the regex for this??

Comment: Do you want to accept leading zeroes? Such as your second case? If so, how many leading zeroes are acceptable? `&#00000031;`?

Comment: Yes, leading 0's need to be tolerated; there can be at most 4 digits, including leading 0's.  Thus, 3, 03, 003, and 0003 are all valid and refer to the same character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [zero-width lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to restrict the number of digits, you can write the rest of the pattern without worrying about the length restriction. Try this:

```
&#(?=x?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})0*([12]?\d|3[01]|x0*1?[0-9A-Fa-f]);
```

Explanation:

```
(?=x?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})  #Restricts the numeric portion to at most four digits, including leading zeroes.
0*                      #Consumes leading zeroes if there is no x.
[12]?\d                 #Allows decimal numbers 0 - 29, inclusive.
3[01]                   #Allows decimal 30 or 31.
x0*1?[0-9A-Fa-f]        #Allows hexadecimal 0 - 1F, inclusive, regardless of case or leading zeroes.
```

This pattern allows leading zeroes after the `x`, but the `(?=x?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})` part prevents them from occurring *before* an `x`.

Comment: A few good answers; this one wins for clarity and great explanation!

Comment: @Ken - Glad I could help. BTW, `&#(?=x?[^;]{1,4})(0*[12]?\d|0*3[01]|x0*1?[0-9A-Fa-f]);` should also work if you find that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
&#(0{0,2}[1-2]\d|000\d|0{0,2}3[01]|x0{0,2}[01][0-9A-Fa-f]);
```

It's not the most elegant, but it should work.

Verified in RegexBuddy.

[image: results]

Comment: Both legitimate bugs. Teach me to dash these off in the middle of a release :).

Comment: Change `0{0,3}[1-2]?\d` to `0{0,2}[1-2]\d|000\d` to correct the extra-leading-0 problem FJ is alluding to.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Yet Another Alternation but yeah...that'll work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work:

```
&#(?:x0{0,2}[01]?[0-9a-fA-F]|0{0,2}(?:[012]?[0-9]|3[01]));
```

Here is a Rubular:
http://www.rubular.com/r/VEYx25Fdpj